# Bind external IP - google cloud engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I've a Google Compute Engine running on Ubuntu 16.04, where i want to start a node.js Websocket Server.
Whenever i try to start listening on the external IP, i get the error: "Cannot assign requested address".
It works with my internal IP or 127.0.0.1, but then i can not access it from outside.

I've created all the necessary firewall rules.

I can not see my external IP when i run ifconfig. Is this a problem? If so, how could i solve this? I already tried to setup a new instance.

And there is no other process listening on that port.

Comment: A simple way to test the accessibility of the external IP is to run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer <port>` in the VM and try accessing it from the internet. It always works for me once I get the firewall set.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38858086/how-to-bind-and-send-from-google-cloud-forwarding-rule-ip-address.  The External IP is not in the local routing table, therefore you can't bind to it - but all requests are DNAT-ed to the internal IP before they reach your VM.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you're binding explicitly to the external IP? You can try omitting the host parameter, which effectively binds to all interfaces, both internal IP and external IP:
[NodeJs: server.listen(port[, hostname][, backlog][, callback])](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback)

If you run `ifconfig` on the VM, you will find the external IP is not there. I believe the external IP is a virtual IP in Compute Engine, the underlying networking infrastructure automatically translates it to the internal IP.

```
$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 42:01:0a:80:00:02  
          inet addr:10.128.0.2  Bcast:10.128.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: fe80::4001:aff:fe80:2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1460  Metric:1
          RX packets:1979 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1363 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:252712 (252.7 KB)  TX bytes:182530 (182.5 KB)
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Comment: Quite correct - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38858086/how-to-bind-and-send-from-google-cloud-forwarding-rule-ip-address